# Dynamic 2D array printing C : why does my array only print out a single line

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to write a dynamic function that prints specified values of a 2D array in C. The values need to be able to be changed, preferably in other functions, and the function should still print the correct display. So I have started with assigning the values in the function itself and printing those, but the 2D structure does not print out, everything is just on one line.

Heres what I want:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6   \n
                \n  
  x x x x x x  1\n
  x x x x x x  2\n
  x x x x x x  3\n
  x x x x x x  4\n
  x x x x x x  5\n
  x x x x x x  6\n
                \n
                \n
```

Heres the code:
As you can see I have tried various tactics… xD

```
/* assigncleanboard: this function is used to initiate the display board by assigning question marks to all cells in the display board at a new game. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 15 

void assigncleanboard(int size) {

    char displayboard[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
    int row=0, col=0;


    for(row=0; row<size; row++) 
    printf("\n");


    if(size<=(MAXSIZE-3) && size>=(MAXSIZE-9)) {

        //for(row=2; row<(size+2); row++) {
        //  displayboard[row][MAXSIZE] = 47+row;
        //  printf(" %c ", displayboard[row][MAXSIZE]);
        //} 



        for(col=0; col<size+3; col++) {
            for(row=0; row<MAXSIZE; row++) {
                if(col == 0 && col == 1 && col == size && col == (size+2) && row == 0 && row == 1 && row == size && row == (size+2) ) {
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                }   
                else {
                    displayboard[row][col] = 88;
                }   
                displayboard[0][col] = 49+col;
                displayboard[row][size+3] = 49+row;
                printf("| %c |", displayboard[row][col]);
            }       
        }   
    }   
        /*

        for(row=2; row<(size+2); row++) {
            for(col=2; col<(size+2); col++)
                displayboard[row][col] = 63;
        } 

                for(row=0; row<size; row++) {
            for(col=0; col<size; col++)     
                displayboard[row][col]=88;
                printf("%c", displayboard[row][col]);
                }

                printf("%c", displayboard[2][MAXSIZE]);

        for(row=2; row<(size+2); row++) {
            for(col=2; col<(size+2); col++)
                printf("%c", displayboard[row][col]);
        } 

        for(row=0; row<size; row++) 
            printf("\n");
    }*/ 

    else 
        printf("Invalid number:\n");

}
```

I also tried this:

```
    if(size<=(MAXSIZE-3) && size>=(MAXSIZE-9)) {

        //for(row=2; row<(size+2); row++) {
        //  displayboard[row][MAXSIZE] = 47+row;
        //  printf(" %c ", displayboard[row][MAXSIZE]);
        //} 



        for(col=0; col<size+4; col++) {
            for(row=0; row<size+4; row++) {
                if(col == 0) 
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                else if(col == 1)
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                else if(col == size)
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                else if(col == size+3)
                    displayboard[row][size+3] = 49+row;     
                else if(row == 0)
                    displayboard[0][col] = 49+col;
                else if(row == 0 && col == size)
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                else if(row == 1 && col == size+3)
                    displayboard[row][col] = 32;
                else 
                    displayboard[row][col] = 88;


                printf(" %c ", displayboard[row][col]);
            }       
        }   
    }
```

Comment: You first for loop has no brackets.  It might print new lines `for row < size` but the rest of your code is only going to run `for col < size +3`

Comment: Okay I have added another version of this, but still the same result.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.  What does size have to do with anything?  Are you just trying to print out all the contents of the array?

Comment: You should debug your code.  Instead of presenting a big chunk of code and asking why it does not work, run it with debugger, or print intermediate results.

Comment: This is a 2D game interface .. 'size' is the user defined size of the board, and size+3 is the padding around the board, including coordinates. In the last column I want to print out row numbers, and the same for the first row. I fixed the mismatched constraints also and maybe fixed the if logic. But it still prints in one line. @Baddack

Comment: It should run more than once, chances are the program is crashing and not finishing.  Do you have values in all the arrays?  If not there could be garbage in there causing the crash if you are accessing an array with garbage in it.

Comment: You have two questions here: how to fill a 2D array and how to print it. And currently you code is wrong both sides. To correctly fill a 2D array, you should use two cascaded loops, one for rows and one for cols *contained in row loop*. And to display by line, you must output a `\n` at the end (or the beginning) of the line and **not** before printing everything else

Answer (score 1):

Your code should run the printf more than once, chances are your program is crashing.  Can you debug you code?  I ran the code below and got multiple printf's.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 15 

void assigncleanboard(void) 
{
    char displayboard[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
    int row = 0, col = 0;

    for(row = 0; row < MAXSIZE; row++) 
    {
        printf("\n");

        for(col = 0; col < MAXSIZE; col++) 
        {
            printf("| %c |", displayboard[row][col]);
        }   
    }
}
```

edit: My print out:

```
| 0.9 || 1.0 || 0.2 || 0.4 || 0.7 || 0.6 || 0.8 || 0.4 || 0.4 || 1.0 || 0.3 || 0.4 || 0.1 || 0.4 || 0.7 |
| 0.4 || 0.5 || 0.9 || 0.4 || 0.9 || 1.0 || 0.7 || 0.1 || 0.2 || 0.3 || 0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6 || 0.1 || 0.1 |
| 0.6 || 0.1 || 0.7 || 0.3 || 0.3 || 0.8 || 0.9 || 0.1 || 0.7 || 0.8 || 0.3 || 0.5 || 0.1 || 0.4 || 0.6 |
| 0.6 || 0.8 || 0.7 || 0.0 || 0.3 || 0.2 || 0.8 || 0.6 || 0.6 || 0.6 || 0.2 || 0.9 || 0.9 || 0.2 || 0.3 |
| 0.0 || 0.2 || 0.3 || 0.3 || 0.4 || 0.2 || 0.7 || 0.8 || 0.0 || 0.9 || 0.5 || 0.4 || 0.3 || 0.7 || 0.6 |
| 0.5 || 0.6 || 0.7 || 0.6 || 0.7 || 0.6 || 0.8 || 0.6 || 0.8 || 0.9 || 0.8 || 0.6 || 0.1 || 0.7 || 0.2 |
| 0.9 || 1.0 || 0.9 || 0.4 || 0.7 || 0.1 || 0.2 || 0.8 || 0.0 || 0.4 || 0.9 || 0.1 || 0.7 || 0.1 || 0.8 |
| 0.8 || 0.6 || 0.9 || 0.9 || 0.1 || 0.5 || 0.2 || 0.3 || 0.5 || 0.7 || 0.2 || 0.6 || 0.5 || 0.4 || 0.6 |
| 0.6 || 0.6 || 0.1 || 0.9 || 0.0 || 0.5 || 0.5 || 0.9 || 0.9 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.8 || 0.7 || 0.2 || 0.8 |
| 0.5 || 0.2 || 0.4 || 1.0 || 0.1 || 0.2 || 0.7 || 0.2 || 0.6 || 0.6 || 0.7 || 0.7 || 0.5 || 0.7 || 0.5 |
| 0.5 || 0.7 || 0.4 || 0.4 || 0.8 || 0.2 || 1.0 || 0.8 || 0.1 || 0.3 || 0.3 || 0.7 || 1.0 || 0.4 || 0.9 |
| 0.7 || 0.5 || 0.1 || 0.6 || 0.2 || 0.0 || 0.2 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.4 || 0.9 || 0.5 || 0.5 || 0.2 || 0.3 |
| 0.9 || 0.0 || 0.2 || 0.4 || 1.0 || 0.5 || 0.4 || 0.3 || 0.5 || 0.6 || 0.6 || 0.4 || 0.4 || 0.7 || 0.8 |
| 0.5 || 0.7 || 0.7 || 0.7 || 0.9 || 0.2 || 0.6 || 0.8 || 0.5 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.2 || 0.2 || 1.0 || 0.8 |
| 0.8 || 0.4 || 0.6 || 0.7 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.5 || 0.6 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.3 || 0.2 || 0.6 || 0.0 || 0.6 |
```

Comment: hmm im not sure what you mean by getting multiple printf's?

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue is your array is empty where you try and print it.  I filled my array with random values in each spot and it printed fine.  But when I didn't assign any values to each spot in the array, when it tried to access the first one, it only printed once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you for your answers. I fixed it, the main problem was \n after every row in the for loop.

```
    int row=0, col=0;



    // Assign initial characters to display board
     for(row=0; row<=size+3; row++) {
        for(col=0; col<=size+3; col++) {
            if(col == 0 || col == 1 || col == size+2 || col == size+3 && row == 0 || row == 1 || row == size+2 || row == size+3) 
                // First two row and column cells are assigned blank spaces.
                displayboard[row][col] = 32;

            else if(row == 0)
                // First row cells are assigned incrememting capital letters for column coordinates
                displayboard[row][col] = col+63;
            else if(col == size+3)
                // Last column cells are assigned incrementing lowercase small letters for row coordinates
                displayboard[row][size+3] = 95+row;     
            else
                // Cells not including the first two rows and columns are assigned question marks
                displayboard[row][col] = 63;


            //printf(" %c ", displayboard[row][col]);
        }       
        //printf("\n");
    }
```

}

- well the printing part got outsourced to this function:

void printboard() 
{

```
int row=0, col=0,n=0;

printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

for(row = 0; row<MAXSIZE; row++) {
    for(col = 0; col<MAXSIZE; col++)
        printf(" %c ", displayboard[row][col]);
    printf("\n"); 
}

printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

}